# XSLT: Reference to entity must end with the ';' delimiter. SXXP0003

Tags: xslt

**Source:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head/>
    <body>
        <p>Here <a href="/cgi-bin/text-idx?&amp;&node=20161118">Link</a></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Transform:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <!-- output just the <body> (without <body>) -->

    <xsl:output method="html"  omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="body/*">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>    
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="head | meta | text()"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Desired Output:**

```
<p>Here <a href="/cgi-bin/text-idx?&amp;&node=20161118">Link</a></p>
```

**Error:**

```
The reference to entity "node" must end with the ';' delimiter. SXXP0003
```

**Solution Constraint:**

- I need to keep the @href as `node=` because that is what the web address is. I cannot delimit it or otherwise change it.
- A later step is an Identity Transform, so I'll need to address the problem there as well.

Comment: `&amp;&` is redundant. Use only `&amp;` instead. Otherwise `node=...` would also be considered an entity and will throw the error you mentioned.

Comment: zx485 you are right, the *amp* is redundant and the transform works without it. Now I have to figure out how to deal with the bad @hrefs that I have.